# get all nodes created in a specific month

Tags: database

I have a custom search form that I posts a year + month, such as
2014-04
I would like to get all nodes created that month, when I create the timestmap I use:
"SELECT .......         AND `changed` >= 'strtotime($date)'"

This is the code for form date:

```
$form['aqar_date'] = array(
'#type' => 'date_select', 
'#title' => t('Date'),
'#prefix' => '<div id="space_replace" class="search-title-date">   <h2>Node date</h2>',
'#suffix' => '</div>',     
'#date_format' => 'Y-m',
'#default_value' => date('Y-m'),
'#date_year_range' => '-4:+0', 
);
```

This is the form submit:

```
$start_date = strtotime($date);
$query = "
SELECT `nid` FROM `node`
WHERE 
`type` = 'custom'
 AND `changed` >= '$start_date'";
```

But I'm not getting, I need a way to specify to only this month period not this month and newer!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you show the actual code you are using?

Comment: @kiamlaluno yep sure I just did, any thoughts?

Comment: What's in `$date`?

Comment: @Clive it's actually the date submitted by the form, "2014-04" for instance, it is in the format of 'Y-m'

Comment: But how are you setting `$date`? With `$date = $form_state['values']['aqar_date'];` or something else?

Comment: @Clive yes I fill it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go with the code.. I have used entity field query to retrieve results.. Code should be self explanatory..  Let me know if you have any difficulty in understanding below code..

```
<?php

$year_month = "2014-04";
$date = date_parse_from_format ("Y-m" ,  $year_month);
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $date['month'], $date['year']);
$first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], 1, $date['year']);
$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, $date['month'], $num, $date['year']);
$entity_type = 'node';
$efq = new EntityFieldQuery();
$efq->entityCondition('entity_type', $entity_type);
$efq->propertyCondition('created', array($first_minute, $last_minute), 'BETWEEN');
$result = $efq->execute();  
dpm($result);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job, though it was hard for me to come up with that it looks shorter than I anticipated :)