# db_query select nodes created this month

Tags: database

I need to query the database directly using php. I am getting my head around this an how to do this using the Drupal database abstraction layer (using db_select and db_query). I need to limit my query to nodes created in the current month. I know that the node table contains the date the node was created in the 'created' column and that this contains a date as a timestamp.

I am not sure how to get the current month and express it as a range of timestamps and return only nodes that were created between the two timestamps.

This code is working to return nodes limited by title:

```
    $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE title = :title", array(':title' => $node->title));
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      // Do something with each $record
      $mynode = node_load($record->nid);
      dpm($mynode);
    }
```

Going to the [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111693/get-all-nodes-created-in-a-specific-month) I have tried to adapt that code to fit my query so I've ended up with:

```
    $year_month = "2014-04";
    $date = date_parse_from_format ("Y-m" ,  $year_month);
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $date['month'], $date['year']);
    $first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], 1, $date['year']);
    $last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, $date['month'], $num, $date['year']);
    $entity_type = 'node';

   $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}  WHERE created = :created", array($first_minute, $last_minute), 'BETWEEN'));
   foreach ($result as $record) {
     // Do something with each $record
     $mynode = node_load($record->nid);
     dpm($mynode);
   }
```

So I worked it out, but as this question has been marked as a duplicate i cannot provide this in an answer, but here we go:

I needed to get the syntax of the between part of the query correct. Working code is:

```
    $year_month = "2014-05";
    $date = date_parse_from_format ("Y-m" ,  $year_month);
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $date['month'], $date['year']);
    $first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date['month'], 1, $date['year']);
    $last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 59, $date['month'], $num, $date['year']);

    $args = array(':first_minute' => $first_minute, ':last_minute' => $last_minute);

    $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE created BETWEEN :first_minute AND :last_minute", $args);
       foreach ($result as $record) {
         // Do something with each $record
         $mynode = node_load($record->nid);
         dpm($mynode);
       }
```